# find integral values k such that sum of expression is minimized

Tags: logic, optimization

Given n values $X_1 , X_2 , ...., X_n$ , where $X_i$ can be positive or negative.
The absolute values of $X_i$ will be less than $100000$ , also $n<=100000$ .
What should be the possible value(s) of $k$ such that $$f(k)=|k| + |X_1 + k| + |X_1 + X_2 + k| + \dots +  |X_1 + X_2 + X_3 +\dots + X_n + k|$$  is minimized .

$| a | $= absolute value of a .

Comment: There is probably a clean and intuitive formula but if you have to solve this numerically, you can cast this as an LPP and be done.

Comment: This feels very much like a problem from some programming contest to me...

Comment: Isn't this just the median (rounded) of $0$, $X_1$, ..., $\sum_i X_i$? EDIT: oops, I should read answers before I comment ;-)

Comment: @PeterKošinár: this is not from programming contest , found it on internet .

Comment: @anon Just out of cusiority, can you provide a link to the original source?

Comment: @PeterKošinár: sure : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720830/minimizing-steps-to-distribute-in-a-candies-in-a-circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll describe the algorithmic approach to this problem.

First, replace the sequence $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ by $\{Y_j\}_{j=0}^{n}$, defined as $Y_j=-\sum_{i=1}^j X_i$. This can be performed in linear time, since we just need to keep adding one term at time to the partial sum.

We're then asked to minimize $$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n |x-Y_j|$$

Now, imagine that $x$ starts from some number which is strictly smaller than all the $Y_j$ and keeps moving towards greater values. Initially, all the absolute values in the sum keep decreasing. This changes once $x$ crosses the first $Y_j$; that particular term reaches zero and starts increasing again as $x$ moves further. Crossing more and more of the $Y_j$, more and more terms start increasing until there are as many "increasing" terms as there are "decreasing" ones. Since all the increasing and decreasing happens at the same rate, this is precisely the point where the value of the sum is minimized; moving further towards greater $x$ can only add more of the increasing ones and remove decreasing ones; thus increasing the value of the sum again.

We are thus seeking the point which has equal number of $Y_j$ to the right and left of it (this point might not be determined uniquely; in some cases it might be any point of interval between two consecutive $Y_j$); which means $x$ is the *median* of the sequence $\{Y_j\}$.

Finding the median can be done easily in time $O(n\log n)$ by sorting the sequence or, using some [clever tricks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), can be reduced to $O(n)$ too; yielding a linear algorithm for the whole problem.